# QPrintPreviewDialog shows result of last print only on Windows 7

Tags: c++, qt5, qwt

I want to print QwtPlot object (from [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) library) and the content of [QTextBrowser](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextbrowser.html) (subclass of QTextEdit) at the next page. Also I need print preview. I use the following code:

```
void MainWindow::printPressed()
{
    QPrintPreviewDialog * printPreview = new QPrintPreviewDialog(this);
    connect(printPreview, SIGNAL(paintRequested(QPrinter *)), this, SLOT(doPrint(QPrinter *)));
    printPreview->exec();
}

void MainWindow::doPrint(QPrinter * printer)
{
    plotRenderer.renderTo(qwtPlot, *printer);
    printer->newPage();
    textBrowser->print(printer);
}
```

Actual printing works just right. But QPrintPreviewDialog shows only the contents of textBrowser, and call to newPage() for print preview returns false. Exactly the same stuff happens when I try to print QTextBrowswer twice (so I don't think that bug is connected with Qwt):

```
void MainWindow::doPrint(QPrinter * printer)
{
    techInfo->print(printer);
    printer->newPage();
    techInfo->print(printer);
}
```

I tried to use QPrintPrevieWidget and got the same behavior. Is there any workaround?